# Maven: jar-with-dependencies include external jar

Tags: java, maven, jar

I would like to include an external jar (specified in the dependencies) inside the jar with dependencies.

pom.xml dependency:

`<dependency>
        <groupId>my.package</groupId>
        <artifactId>my-artifact</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${basedir}\..\lib\my-artifact.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>`

Here is the code for jar-with-dependencies:

`<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>CtrlpConversion</id>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                         <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>my.package.Main</mainClass>
                            <packageName>my.package</packageName>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <finalName>MyExecutable</finalName>
                    <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                </configuration>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>single</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>`

The .jar generated by this pom.xml does not include the classes of my-artifact.jar. And when I try to run the main I get the following error:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: my/package/ClassThatINeed
        at my.package.Main.main(Main.java:29)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: my.package.ClassThatINeed
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 1 more`

I would love to have some help in finding the solution to this issue. Thank you!!

Comment: You need to configure classpath in your jar;s manifest file please refer to link I duplicated with

Comment: Are the classes actually missing? Open up the jar file using a zip utility and see if they are actually in there. Chances are, your manifest file has an incorrect classpath.

Comment: Jigar, I've added <addClasspath>true</addClasspath> but I'm having the same identical behavior.

Comment: Ryan, the classes are actually missing in the JAR

Comment: So `my.package.ClassThatINeed` is there in your MANIFEST.mf's classpath entry relatively?

Comment: The class is not in the jar file. (Like the other dependencies I have).

Comment: then where is the java source located in project directory structure ?